# 'Form1.Label1' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a function inside another class of my c# program, but I get this error. The function needs to the `Text` of a `Label`.

Code of my class:

```
form1 frm = new form1();
public void Menu()
{
    frm.label1.Text = "test";
}
```

Code of my main program:

```
public form1()
{
    Commands obj = new Commands();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Error:

> CS0122  C# is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the error message really said "C# is inaccessible". I suspect it says "label1 is inaccessible", presumably because the `label1` field is private? It's hard to tell with so little context. It would also help if you'd show which line the error message refers to.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are trying to refer to something that is a private or protected instead of public?

Comment: Make label1 public at designer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# using winform controls in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133894/c-sharp-using-winform-controls-in-another-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your `Form1.Designer.cs` you will see that your controls are declared as `private` fields by default:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
```

They should be [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), if you want to access them outside the form. *A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field.*:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Label Label1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: thank you, this was the problem... im kina a newb but im learning thank you again !

Comment: You could also have a property to get/set the text of the label, rather than accessing the whole label itself.