# Get items like table adapter marked as internal from 2nd project using their names

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am working on a C# winform project in WinForms that references a second project build in VB. In addition to the normal controls such as button or label, we can have another item such as tableadapters or dataSets that appear in the bottom of the designer form in the VB project.
Now, from the C# project the question is how can I get such items using their names?

I've tried this to get access to VB project's form controls using this code:

```
this.Controls.Find("controlName");
```

Can I do something similar with items such as TableAdapters or is there any way using reflection to access given their names?

Comment: You question seems unclear to me. Do you want to access this controls from code-behind?

Comment: Yes. in fact i need to access to table adapter of one form in another form code behind

Comment: Then check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46155570/2946329

Comment: Thanks. but it doesn't solve the problem. my main project wrote by VB.net and  table adapters are defined in designer with "Friend WithEvents"  but i want to access them in another code wrote in C# and added as a library in my main project. table adapter added automatically to form and i can't change its modifier

Comment: You've tagged the question in C# and also you have stated *I am working on a C# winform project* and in the above comment you are saying *my main project wrote by VB.NET*. Your question is unclear. Please read this page first, since I see you are new to SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: main project is in VB.net but the library i am writing, is in C# and i must access to the table adapters added to VB form automatically in my library code having only their names

Comment: S.Akbari is correct.  If you have a reference to the form that would allow something like `Controls.Find()`, then you can do what the linked answer suggests.  Either you can access the Form or you can't.  And if you can, then create a property to expose it and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableAdapter` is a component and you can not find components by name. There is a big difference between components and controls and they don't have `Name` property.

To find components by name, you rely on reflection. For example you can create such method:

```
public T GetMember<T>(string name) where T : class
{
    var field = this.GetType().GetField(name,
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (field == null)
        return null;
    return (T)field.GetValue(this);
}
```

Then to find any component, you can write such code:

```
var t = GetMember<System.Windows.Forms.Timer>("timer1");
```

Comment: The question is about finding components by name, something like `this.components["tableAdapter1"]` which doesn't make sense. That's the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the comments, it looks like you have a WinForms project built in VB.NET with a form whose controls are set to `Friend` (`internal` is C#'s equivalent).

Just need to instantiate the form and iterate over its controls to get at the controls. If you want to access via strongly typed property, you'd have to change its access modifier to `Public`. However if you know the name of the control;

```
YourVbForm form = new YourVbForm();
Control c = form.Controls["yourControlName"];
```

That said, using magic strings to identify a component isn't the way to go in a production system. If you have control over the VB project and can modify it then the previously mentioned approach of setting the modifier should be sufficient. However, if that doesn't work or you want to have a bit more control over how it should be accessed, you could have a publicly accessible property like;

```
Public Property TableAdapter MyAdapter
    Get
        Return _myAdapter
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: thank for answering. your code works for controls like buttons but it doesn't work for tableAdapters even if i change the modifier to public

Comment: You're not wrong, but any solution that requires the name of a thing is doomed to fail.  Names change, they're not reliable.  The linked answer in the comments is the only good one.

Comment: @NazaninFaghihi how are you placing a `TableAdapter` onto the `Form`? I've tested with several types of components and setting the `Modifier` property to `Public` works for me

Comment: @DonBoitnott fair point, I was giving a sample. I've updated with a more production-ready solution, especially as the OP states that the VB project can be tweaked.